# Загрузка файла NodeJS

Tags: node.js

вообщем решил позаимствовать скрипт по загрузке файлов на сервер. Т.к. в бэке я не особо разбираюсь столкнулся с ошибкой, так при  выборе файла и непосредственного нажатия на кнопку "Отправить" получаю ошибку ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. В коментариях к скрипту была пометка, что требуется модуль express-fileupload. Скачав Node.JS и открыв командую строку я его подключил командой npm install --save express-fileupload и мне выдало вот это

```
C:\Users\profr>npm install --save express-fileupload
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Users\profr\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Users\profr\package.json'
 npm WARN profr No description
 npm WARN profr No repository field.
 npm WARN profr No README data
 npm WARN profr No license field.

+ express-fileupload@1.1.1-alpha.1
updated 1 package and audited 57 packages in 1.582s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Вот сам скрипт

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var upload = require('express-fileupload');
const http = require('http');
http.Server(app).listen(80); // make server listen on port 80

app.use(upload()); // configure middleware

console.log("Server Started at port 80");

app.get('/',function(req,res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
})
app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
 console.log(req.files);
 if(req.files.upfile){
   var file = req.files.upfile,
    name = file.name,
    type = file.mimetype;
  var uploadpath = __dirname + 'C:/Users/profr/OneDrive/Desktop/NodeJS/uploads/' + name;
file.mv(uploadpath,function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log("File Upload Failed",name,err);
    res.send("Error Occured!")
  }
  else {
    console.log("File Uploaded",name);
    res.send('Done! Uploading files')
  }
});
}
else {
res.send("No File selected !");
res.end();
};
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install --save пытается установить пакет локально в существующий проект, а проект у вас не инициализирован.

Сделайте следующее:
Создайте папку  и в ней набирайте команды

```
npm init    //Следуйте инструкциям. В качестве входного файла укажите имя файла вашего скрипта
npm i --save express express-fileupload
```

скопируйте в папку ваш скрипт

запустите его:

```
node myscript.js
```

Comment: Вообщем через консоль создал папку где будет храниться проект назвав создал папку, подключил модуль и запустил папку и после запуска висит, так и нужно? 
C:\Users\profr\NPIM>node code.js
Server Started at port 80

Comment: Не висит а слушает на 80 порту. Так и должно быть. Далее - открывайте браузер и переходите на localhost. Должна загрузиться страничка index.html, если она есть в папке со скриптом. Вообще, советую прочитать базовую информацию по express и node.js https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: спасибо, все заработало, обязательно почитаю!